# Style information is lost when printing webpage?

Tags: printing, stylesheet, printing-web-page

I've set the media to all, but when printing a page and clicking "preview" much of the style information is missing. Any idea why?

Comment: You should tell what browser you tested.

Comment: Browser printing settings has an option of disabling the background images. Have you noticed it?

Comment: Didn't realize this was default on OSX. Thanks.